# тихая in fem.+instrumentalis?

Tags: грамматика

What will тихая ночь be in feminine instrumentalis?

http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morph.cgi?flags=endnnnnn&root=config&word=%F2%E8%F5%E0%FF

Comment: Both are possible, "тихой" is usually used and it's neutral, "тихою" is OK too, and it's more poetic.

Answer (score 2):

It will be `тихой ночью` in feminine instrumentalis, `тихою` is a poetic form that is not normally used in everyday communication.